# mouseover not working in ie7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Having problems in IE7.It does not show me the "mouse over- drop down".
This "mouse over" was working well till yesterday also works in FireFox.

There  a table that displays all the current documents.When one does a mouse over on a given document,it displays a list of options in form of a dropdown.

Can it be corrected in IE settings etc?

I am not talking about the javascript here , only the user settings.I am strictly the end user in this case.Also i tried downloading IE8 and it stopped in between.Hence I checked the ActiveX settings in IE and it was enabled.

Kindly help.

Comment: your question is too vague for anyone to realistically be able to help you. What is the code that shows the dropdown? What does ActiveX have to do with this? User Settings?

Comment: superuser.com do not post on stackoverflow this is not a programming question.

Comment: something changed. if it was working yesterday, and not working today, you need to find out what changed in that time.

Comment: I am strictly the end user in this case.Also i tried downloading IE8 and it stopped in between.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems well-founded, but it's difficult to discern what the question is exactly. Could you please elaborate? Source code may also help.

If you'd like to go a more DIY route, try throwing your code at [JSLint](http://jslint.com/). It will magically surface errors you didn't see.

Comment: I am strictly the end user in this case.Also i tried downloading IE8 and it stopped in between.

Comment: Excuse me. I misread the question.

Even if you are the user, you may still be able to extract the JS source code to help out the developer. ;) But perhaps JonH is correct here, superuser.com might be better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore generates a lot of temporary and debug code files.  This could be the problem.  I would try deleting all of the temp/debug files, and see if that helps.  They are scattered throughout the site, so you have to hunt for the debug directories.

However, I do see a lot of WEIRD JavaScript things with SiteCore.  Sometimes I will load the content editor, and it wont work because of JS errors.  I clear my cache and refresh and it works fine.  But nothing in the JavaScript *should* be changing, since it would be the scripts from the vendor.  I don't go in and change JS.  Maybe they are generating JS somewhere.